# Calculate width for each list item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a new jquery function to do what this line of CSS does now:

```
#progressbar li {width: calc(100% / 5); /* divide by number of steps */}
```

This jquery code I created does not work:

```
var count = $("#progressbar").children().length
result = parseInt(100) / parseInt(count);
$( "#progressbar > li" ).css( "width", "result%" );
```

This is to set the width of multi-page form progress bars for forms of varying lengths and steps. Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks all. Its working now, but if you have a better way let me know. I am creating several new forms online. I have the first two linked here:

http://new-site.autouplinktech.com/forms/form-video360.html
http://new-site.autouplinktech.com/forms/form-inteliPhoto.html

I am also running into a lot of issues implementing jquery Validation on my forms since it also uses multi-step to show each fieldset separately, but that can be the topic of another post here.

Comment: `$( "#progressbar > li" ).css( "width", result+"%" );`

Comment: you don't need to `parseInt()`

Comment: I am absolutely sure there is a better approach for what you are trying to do. can we see this live?

Comment: You can only use parseInt for result when calculating. result = parseInt(100 / count); And the mistake is "result%". You have to change it to result+"%"

Comment: Don't forget the radix on parseInt(): `parseInt(count, 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$( "#progressbar > li" ).css( "width", "result%" );`

Should be:

```
$( "#progressbar > li" ).css( "width", result + "%" );
```

Also, add a semi-colon to the first statement:

```
var count = $("#progressbar").children().length;
```

[This isn't the source of the problem of course though :)].